# Searching a name in a gridview C#

Tags: c#

[This is the table. On the right are the names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nAFI.png)I have a gridview that shows a table from the database. I want to search a name in the gridview using a textbox and a button. This is what i have so far. When i want to search I get in a messagebox this: object reference is not set on an instance of an object.

```
private void btn_zoek_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string searchValue = tb_SearchOverzicht.Text;

    metroGrid1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    try
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in metroGrid1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
            {
                row.Selected = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is not working? Are there any errors or something you dont know how to continue with? I can't see a clear question here.

Comment: I'm sorry. When i want to search i get as an error message: object reference is not set on an instance of an object. So i can't search for any names

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: It's a messagebox when a run it

Comment: Try it again without your `try` `catch` code and edit your question with your real question and the error code, so other will see the important details faster

Comment: Can you try at debug mode and find exactly which line is problem.

Comment: I doesn't give a error at any line

Answer (score 1):

Check if the values and object you are trying to work with are filled with data and not `null`.

In your row

```
if (row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
```

you should check first, if the cell exists and has value, like this:

```
if(row.Cells[2] != null && row.Cells[2].Value.ToString() == searchValue)
{
     // Some code
}
```

and just to be sure, check if your `searchValue` is not empty or without any chars or maybe even correct formatted:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchValue))
```

but I dont think this is necessary here, just nice to have.
The goal here is: Not all values have to be filled. It can appear that a cell doesnt have value in that column, the row may be the filter row or even empty, or worst: the grid isn't even initialized. So please try to check if values or objects are filled before using them.

Comment: i've tried it. But it gives the error:'DataGridViewCell' does not contain a definition for 'HasValue' and no extension method 'HasValue' accepting a first argument of type 'DataGridViewCell' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @TyroneFabies Interesting, but there is no such error with `.Value`? Hm, sorry, didn't know that. I will edit my Answer, just give me a second.

Comment: Well this one didn't help either. It gives the same error message as the first one in the message box

Comment: @TyroneFabies Ok. As you can see we won't get far here without proper error analysis. The `try catch` code will throw before you can see the error, so you need to remove that peace of code for now. After that, you place a breakpoint right after the `click` event from you button. As soon as your application reaches the breakpoint, it will pause you can hover above the object and values to see if its filled and with what its filled and you will see where exactly it crashes. Try that and tell us what you found.

Comment: @TyroneFabies In case you need some help to debug your code, [Microsoft got an excellent doc for this!](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2017)